# Запятые при использовании фразы "уже не помню какой..."

Tags: пунктуация, сложное-предложение

Есть следующее предложение:

> Какое-то время тому назад уже не помню какой полицейский в Женеве брал
> показания [...]

Не могу понять, нужны ли запятые где-то между тем, кто уже не помнит, и полицейским в Женеве. Скажите, пожалуйста, верный вариант и правило. Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Ой-ё.

"Не помню какой полицейский" - сказуемое в приведённом Вами определенно-личном предложении. Не надо ничего дробить запятыми. Глагол "помнить" здесь лексически неполнозначен.

Сравните:

*Какое-то время тому назад уже не помню кто в Женеве брал показания...*

Comment: Давненько не общались. Вечер добрый, Галина. _"Не помню какой полицейский" - сказуемое..._ А что же тогда такое "брал"?

Comment: Римуля, привет! Тут что-то связанное с инверсией... "Брал" действительно зависло, но не надо запятых.

Comment: да, я без запятых и оставила на свой страх и риск. спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

У Розенталя есть примеры и посложнее ([Выделение определённо-личного предложения](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/463350)):

> В разговорной речи часто встречаются сложноподчиненные предложения с главной частью, расположенной внутри
> придаточной: Без него не знаю что бы делал; Прошло не помню сколько
> времени; Он не скажу чтобы был симпатичен; Так мы пробежали не считал
> сколько километров. (https://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=198)

У нас же можно интерпретировать предложение как вставную конструкцию (два отдельных предложения):

```
Какое-то время тому назад (я уже не помню какой) полицейский в Женеве брал показания.
```

Но, в свете примеров Розенталя, можно не значит нужно. Знаки препинания лучше не ставить.

Лучше интерпретировать предложение как сложноподчиненное:

```
Я уже не помню, какой полицейский в Женеве брал показания какое-то время тому назад.
```