# Выделение определённо-личного предложения

Tags: пунктуация

Какое предложение будет правильным с точки зрения пунктуации:

1. Этот человек планирует не знаю что;
2. Этот человек планирует, не знаю, что.

Comment: Этот человек планирует что-то, не знаю что.

Comment: Этот человек планирует неизвестно что.

Answer (score 1):

С точки зрения пунктуации - Этот человек планирует не знаю что.

А вот само предложение странное. Есть просторечные (народные) фразеологизмы ***незнамо что, невесть что***, а Ваше - это переделка на новый лад, может, областное. Слышала ***не зная где***, а такого не слышала.

https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ogegova/123646

Comment: У Розенталя есть такие примеры: *В разговорной речи часто встречаются сложноподчиненные предложения с главной частью, расположенной внутри придаточной: Без него **не знаю** что бы делал; Прошло **не помню** сколько времени; Он **не скажу** чтобы был симпатичен; Так мы пробежали **не считал** сколько километров.* (http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=198) Может, в этом вопросе такой же случай?

Comment: Тогда смысл был бы: Я не знаю, что планирует этот человек. Не зная контекста, трудно ответить. Похоже, здесь всё же отрицательная коннотация: Этот человек планирует (что?) не знаю что = незнамо что, т. е. что-то странное. Тогда это слитное сочетание,по форме застывшее определённо-личное предложение, занимающее место дополнения.

Comment: Хотя может быть и Ваш вариант, контекста же нет.